# Channel form date picker issue

Tags: safecracker, date

i recently upgraded to expression engine from 2.6.2 and 2.8.2 and made the change to channel forms from safecracker.Everything went well and the forms are working fine but I am having a issue with my date picker field. It still works but seems to have lost the path to its style and im not sure what to change to fix this.
See picture below

Any help is greatly appreciated

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Link to the CSS.

From the docs:
https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/channel_form/#including-assets